# Getting the Contents of a Specific Directory on the SDCard

Tags: android, sd-card

How would I go about getting an array of all the files in a specific directory on the sdcard, i.e. /ringtones/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple. Just do the following:

```
File dir = new File(path);
String[] files = dir.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking in a specific location and obviously if you are looking in the ringtones directory you want audio type files. Here is exactly how to accomplish that task.

I have created an example application for you that shows exactly how to accomplish this task

[Source Code: Find files by type + play media file](http://androidworkz.com/2010/07/08/source-code-find-files-by-type-play-media-file/)

Answer (score -1):

You should try this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Hope I have helped.